# Nifi - How to put data into Hive database?

Tags: hive, apache-nifi

I am building a Nifi flow to get json elements from a kafka and write them into a Have table.

However, there is very little to none documentation about the processors and how to use them.

What I plan to do is the following:

```
kafka consume --> ReplaceText --> PutHiveQL
```

[image]

Consuming kafka topic is doing great. I receive a json string.

I would like to extract the json data (with replaceText) and put them into the hive table (PutHiveQL).

However, I have absolutely no idea how to do this. Documentation is not helping and there is no precise example of processor usage (or I could not find one).

- Is my theoretical solution valid ?
- How to extract json data, build a HQL query and send it to my local hive database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basicly you want to transform your record from kafka into HQL request then send the request to putHiveQl processor.

I am not sur that the transformation kafka record -> putHQL can be done with replacing text ( seam little bit hard/ tricky) . In general i use custom groovy script processor to do this.

---

**Edit**

Global overview :

[image]

**EvaluateJsonPath**

This extract the properties `timestamp` and `uuid` of my Json flowfile and put them as attribute of the flowfile.

[image]

**ReplaceText**

This set flowfile string to empty string and replaces it by the `replacement value` property, in which I build the query.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can directly inject the streaming data using Puthivestreaming process.
create an ORC table with the strcuture matching to the flow and pass the flow to PUTHIVE3STreaming processor it works.